# C++ code of Q-learning Algorithm has no output

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to run the following Q-learning algorithm code but, there was no output. Knowing that I found this code in an online blog, In addition, I'm using Xcode IDE .Thank you for your help in advance.

```
 // Author:     John McCullock
// Date:        11-05-05
// Description: Q-Learning Example 1.

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

const int qSize = 6;
const double gamma = 0.8;
const int iterations = 10;
int initialStates[qSize] = {1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 0};

int R[qSize][qSize] =  {{-1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1},
            {-1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 100},
            {-1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1},
            {-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1},
            {0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 100},
            {-1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 100}};

int Q[qSize][qSize];
int currentState;

void episode(int initialState);
void chooseAnAction();
int getRandomAction(int upperBound, int lowerBound);
void initialize();
int maximum(int state, bool returnIndexOnly);
int reward(int action);

int main(){

    int newState;

    initialize();

    //Perform learning trials starting at all initial states.
    for(int j = 0; j <= (iterations - 1); j++){
        for(int i = 0; i <= (qSize - 1); i++){
            episode(initialStates[i]);
        } // i
    } // j

    //Print out Q matrix.
    for(int i = 0; i <= (qSize - 1); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= (qSize - 1); j++){
            cout << setw(5) << Q[i][j];
            if(j < qSize - 1){
                cout << ",";
            }
        } // j
        cout << "\n";
    } // i
    cout << "\n";

    //Perform tests, starting at all initial states.
    for(int i = 0; i <= (qSize - 1); i++){
        currentState = initialStates[i];
        newState = 0;
        do {
            newState = maximum(currentState, true);
            cout << currentState << ", ";
            currentState = newState;
        } while(currentState < 5);
        cout << "5" << endl;
    } // i

    return 0;
}

void episode(int initialState){

    currentState = initialState;

    //Travel from state to state until goal state is reached.
    do {
        chooseAnAction();
    } while(currentState == 5);

    //When currentState = 5, run through the set once more to
    //for convergence.
    for(int i = 0; i <= (qSize - 1); i++){
        chooseAnAction();
    } // i
}

void chooseAnAction(){

    int possibleAction;

    //Randomly choose a possible action connected to the current state.
    possibleAction = getRandomAction(qSize, 0);

    if(R[currentState][possibleAction] >= 0){
        Q[currentState][possibleAction] = reward(possibleAction);
        currentState = possibleAction;
    }
}

int getRandomAction(int upperBound, int lowerBound){

    int action;
    bool choiceIsValid = false;
    int range = (upperBound - lowerBound) + 1;

    //Randomly choose a possible action connected to the current state.
    do {
        //Get a random value between 0 and 6.
        action = lowerBound + int(range * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0));
        if(R[currentState][action] > -1){
            choiceIsValid = true;
        }
    } while(choiceIsValid == false);

    return action;
}

void initialize(){

    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    for(int i = 0; i <= (qSize - 1); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= (qSize - 1); j++){
            Q[i][j] = 0;
        } // j
    } // i
}

int maximum(int state, bool returnIndexOnly){
// if returnIndexOnly = true, a Q matrix index is returned.
// if returnIndexOnly = false, a Q matrix element is returned.

    int winner;
    bool foundNewWinner;
    bool done = false;

    winner = 0;

    do {
        foundNewWinner = false;
        for(int i = 0; i <= (qSize - 1); i++){
            if((i < winner) || (i > winner)){     //Avoid self-comparison.
                if(Q[state][i] > Q[state][winner]){
                    winner = i;
                    foundNewWinner = true;
                }
            }
        } // i

        if(foundNewWinner == false){
            done = true;
        }

    } while(done = false);

    if(returnIndexOnly == true){
        return winner;
    }else{
        return Q[state][winner];
    }
}

int reward(int action){

    return static_cast<int>(R[currentState][action] + (gamma * maximum(action, false)));
}
```

Comment: I need your help, my debugger isn't working, so can you run it through yours?  Execute each statement separately and watch the values of variables.  Edit your post with the results so I can see them.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Thomas Matthews, I will chek  the code's  statements. (Just for your information) there are online debuggers for most of the programming languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more specific about what the not-portable behavior was, the calculation `int(range * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0))` was overflowing in a way that made it impossible to reach the escape state, so there was an infinite loop going on.

This can be avoided by doing the division first and then the multiplication like so:

```
int(range * (rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)))
```

The use of floats is sort of unnecessary as a whole so you can also do

```
( rand() / (RAND_MAX / range))
```

The reason why this didn't happen with Visual Studio is that its standard library implementation of `rand()` only generates numbers between `0` and `0x7FFF`, so the multiplication did not overflow.

Whereas the standard library implementation of gcc (and presumably clang) generates values between `0` and `0x7FFFFFFF`.

Specifically the "escape value" is 5 I believe.  You can imagine that for `(val / (0x7FFFFFFF+1.0))` there exists no integer `val` that can make this expression evaluate to `5` (since that would require it be `(INT_MAX+1)*5`).

Comment: your explanation gives  me  a deep understanding  of  this problem. During the last few weeks I did check the code line by line without any success of solving the problem.... you are the best Peter !!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I tried compiling it with g++. And you are right. No output.

But with Visual C++, This is the output.

```
    0,    0,    0,    0,  392,    0
    0,    0,    0,  312,    0,  491
    0,    0,    0,  313,    0,    0
    0,  392,  245,    0,  392,    0
  292,    0,    0,  313,    0,  491
    0,  392,    0,    0,  392,  489

1, 5
3, 1, 5
5, 5
2, 3, 1, 5
4, 5
0, 4, 5
Press any key to continue
```

Comment: Thank you very much"Software_Designer" , yes I found that too,  but the question is , why it does work with Visual C++ and not with other IDES  such as Xcode, Eclipse and online code  compile & run ? the problem is  this algorithm code must be part of my ns-3 simulation that runs on Eclipse. Thus,  I need to run it with  something different than Visual C++. I will appreciate it if you can lend  me  a hand of help.